# how to view only the login person post in cake php blog example?

Tags: cakephp

Cake php blog example with auth login pages here index() method i have to disply his own post other post should not be display .. here i changed but it shows error so changed to basic can any one help me

controller/PatientslistController.php

```
<?php

    class PatientslistController extends AppController {
        public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session');
        public $components = array('Session');

       public function index() {
           $this->set('posts', $this->Patientslist->find('all'));

        }

        public function view($id) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            $post = $this->Patientslist->findById($id);

            if (!$post) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }
            $this->set('post', $post);

                }
                public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //Added this line
            $this->request->data['Patientslist']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
            if ($this->Patientslist->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }

      /*  public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Post->create();
                if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to add your post.'));
            }
        }
        */
        public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        $post = $this->Patientslist->findById($id);
        if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
        }

        if ($this->request->is(array('Patientslist', 'put'))) {
            $this->Patientslist->id = $id;
            if ($this->Patientslist->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
        }

        if (!$this->request->data) {
            $this->request->data = $post;
        }
    }
    public function delete($id) {
        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }

        if ($this->Patientslist->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(
                __('The post with id: %s has been deleted.', h($id))
            );
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        // All registered users can add posts
        if ($this->action === 'add') {
            return true;
        }

        // The owner of a post can edit and delete it
        if (in_array($this->action, array('edit', 'delete'))) {
            $postId = $this->request->params['pass'][0];
            if ($this->Patientslist->isOwnedBy($postId, $user['id'])) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return parent::isAuthorized($user);
    }
    }
    ?>
```

**model/Patientslist.php**

```
<?php class Patientslist extends AppModel {

    public function isOwnedBy($post, $user) {
    return $this->field('id', array('id' => $post, 'user_id' => $user)) === $post;
}
}
?>
```

**view/Patientslist/index.ctp**

```
<h1>Blog posts</h1>
<p><?php echo $this->Html->link('Add Post', array('action' => 'add')); ?></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
        <th>Created</th>
    </tr>

<!-- Here's where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post['Patientslist']['id']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $this->Html->link(
                    $post['Patientslist']['title'],
                    array('action' => 'view', $post['Patientslist']['id'])
                );
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->postLink(
                    'Delete',
                    array('action' => 'delete', $post['Patientslist']['id']),
                    array('confirm' => 'Are you sure?')
                );
            ?>
            <?php
                echo $this->Html->link(
                    'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $post['Patientslist']['id'])
                );
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $post['Patientslist']['created']; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</table>
```

Comment: What is the Error ? Post the Error

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint thanks for responding .posted code are error free code i need to filter by user added post to display in index() method in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index() {
   $this->set('posts', $this->Patientslist->find('all', array(
                                'conditions' => array(
                                'Patientslist.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));

   }
```

Change "user_id" with related user field in PatientLists table.